# How Can I Pull Specific Links From A Webpage Using Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'd like to pull specific links from a webpage using Python. In my example below I'm viewing a form 8-K from the SEC website with several links in it. A link for a press release but also a link to Table of Contents.

Here, I only want links that are considered Exhibits. All exhibits on any 8-K form should fall within the ' Item 9.01.  Financial Statements and Exhibits' section.

The code below will get all links on the 8-K but I only want the links within the Exhibit section.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Provide the URL and Headers
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/707549/000070754923000005/lrcx-20230123.htm"
headers = {"User-Agent":"INSERT YOUR USER AGENT INFO HERE"}


# Send a GET request to retrieve the HTML content
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
html_content = response.text

# Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

# Find all the links in the HTML
all_links = soup.find_all("a")

# Extract the URLs from the links and print them
for link in all_links:
    url = link.get("href")
    print(url)
```

Comment: I'm still having issues with this. The below comments do work for pulling the exhibit URL's. However, the examples given pull the same exhibit URL's multiple times and I'm not sure why. For example, using this URL: https://app.quotemedia.com/data/downloadFiling?webmasterId=90423&ref=117232484&type=HTML&symbol=DT&companyName=Dynatrace+Inc.&formType=8-K&formDescription=Current+report+pursuant+to+Section+13+or+15%28d%29&dateFiled=2023-02-09 . I get multiple links for the same exhibit.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any filter fields like `class` or `id` so that I could filter the specific exhibit `a tags`.

But, I noticed that the exhibit urls have the word "exhibit" on them, so the following code could find all those exhibit urls.

```
# Extract the URLs from the links and print them
base_endpoint = '/'.join(url.split('/')[:-1])
for link in all_links:
    a_url = link.get("href")
    if 'exhibit' in url:
        print(f'{base_endpoint}/{a_url}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page, you can search for all links with word `exibit` in their `href=`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/707549/000070754923000005/lrcx-20230123.htm'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('[href*="exhibit"]'):
    print(link.text)
    print(url.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[0] + '/' + link['href'])
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Press Release dated January 25, 2023 announcing financial results for the fiscal quarter ended December 25, 2022
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/707549/000070754923000005/lrcx_exhibitx991xq2x2023.htm
```

---

EDIT: To remove duplicates you can use for example `set()`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/707549/000070754923000005/lrcx-20230123.htm'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

base_url = url.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[0] + '/'

out = set()
for link in soup.select('[href*="exhibit"]'):
    out.add(base_url + link['href'])

print(*out, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/707549/000070754923000005/lrcx_exhibitx991xq2x2023.htm
```

Comment: This is working great thank you! The only issue I'm finding is duplicates. When I run this code some of the 8-K's are giving me duplicates of the same exhibit. For example, a webpage for the 8-K only has 1 exhibit. This script is giving me several results for the exact same exhibit. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ericander1 You can use `set()` to remove duplicates. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm still having issues with duplicate URL's with the code. For example, using this URL: https://app.quotemedia.com/data/downloadFiling?webmasterId=90423&ref=117232484&type=HTML&symbol=DT&companyName=Dynatrace+Inc.&formType=8-K&formDescription=Current+report+pursuant+to+Section+13+or+15%28d%29&dateFiled=2023-02-09. I get multiple links. Any ideas?